# How to refer FIrebase Child in Child record in Firebase Recycler adapter to show in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have written code to list contacts in recycler view. But it doesn't display value in recycler view. The code is given below.

HomeActivity.java

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private RecyclerView PList;
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<project, ProjViewHolder> FBRA;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
PList = findViewById(R.id.ProjList);
PList.setHasFixedSize(true);
PList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Contacts");
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<project> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<project>().setQuery(mDatabase, project.class).build();

FBRA = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<project, ProjViewHolder>(options) {
@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProjViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull project model) {
String proj_key = getRef(position).getKey();
holder.cpname.setText(model.getCname());
holder.cplocation.setText(model.getCcity());
holder.ccname.setText(model.getPcontact());
holder.ccdesig.setText(model.getPdesig());
}

@Override
public ProjViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.proj_row, parent, false);
return new ProjViewHolder(view);
}
};
PList.setAdapter(FBRA);
FBRA.startListening();
}

public class ProjViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
TextView cpname, cplocation, ccname, ccdesig;
ProjViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
super(itemView);
cpname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.FCName);
cplocation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.FCLocation);
ccname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.FPName);
ccdesig = itemView.findViewById(R.id.FPDesig);
}
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
super.onStop();
FBRA.stopListening();
}
```

FormActivity.java

```
public class FormActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText CName, PContact,PDesig, CCity;
private FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;
private Button Fbtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_form);

CName = findViewById(R.id.CompName);
PContact = findViewById(R.id.PContact);
PDesig = findViewById(R.id.PDesig);
CCity = findViewById(R.id.CCity);
      
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.save, menu);
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

String dCName = CName.getText().toString().trim();
String dPContact = PContact.getText().toString().trim();
String dPDesig = PDesig.getText().toString().trim();
String dCCity = CCity.getText().toString().trim();

String name = CName.getText().toString().trim();
DatabaseReference mDbRef = mDatabase.getReference().child("Contacts").child(name).push();
mDbRef.child("cname").setValue(dCName);
mDbRef.child("pcontact").setValue(dPContact);
mDbRef.child("pdesig").setValue(dPDesig);
mDbRef.child("ccity").setValue(dCCity);
Toast.makeText(FormActivity.this, "Contact Submitted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Intent intent = new Intent(FormActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
}
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Project.class

```
public class project {

   String cname, pcontact, pdesig, ccity;

   public project(){

   }

    public project(String cname, String pcontact, String pdesig, String ccity) {
        this.cname = cname;
        this.pcontact = pcontact;
        this.pdesig = pdesig;
        this.ccity = ccity;
    }

    public String getCname() {
        return cname;
    }

    public void setCname(String cname) {
        this.cname = cname;
    }

   public String getPcontact() {
        return pcontact;
    }

    public void setPcontact(String pcontact) {
        this.pcontact = pcontact;
    }

    public String getPdesig() {
        return pdesig;
    }

    public void setPdesig(String pdesig) {
        this.pdesig = pdesig;
    }

    public String getCcity() {
        return ccity;
    }

    public void setCcity(String ccity) {
        this.ccity = ccity;
    }

    }
```

HomeActivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:id="@+id/ProjList"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

ProjRow.xml

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="2dp">
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/FCName"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAllCaps="true"
android:elegantTextHeight="true"
android:textColor="@color/colorBlue"
android:maxLength="25"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:textSize="16dp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
/>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/FCLocation"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:textAllCaps="true"
android:elegantTextHeight="true"
android:textColor="@color/colorDark"
android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:textSize="14dp"
/>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/FPName"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/FCName"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:elegantTextHeight="true"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="@color/colorText"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:paddingRight="3dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:textSize="15dp"
/>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/FPDesig"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/FCName"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:padding="5dp"
android:textSize="14dp"
android:textColor="@color/colorNext"
android:elegantTextHeight="true"
/>
</RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

the code is working fine without error. But the intended value is not captured from database. If `push()` is removed from `DatabaseReference mDbRef = mDatabase.getReference().child("Contacts").child(name).push();` , it works absolutely fine. but it overwrites on existing data while adding new data for the same 'name'. After adding push, the data are getting stored in sub child record. Please guide me how to refer and get back the data in recycleview adapter.

The each record stored under 'Contacts' before adding `push()`but overwrites when added a person for the same company.

[image: Before adding push()]

After adding `push()` each record stored under company name with unique key.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo Updated with screenshot of db structure.